# Inserting different map object to CartoType map

Tags: openstreetmap

I can add one mapobject by using:

```
m_framework.InsertPointMapObject(m_framework.GetMemoryMapHandle(),"amenity",
                                             32.791576, 39.909264,
                                             CartoType.CoordType.Degree,
                                             "AHMET YILMAZ\n06DY1998\n",
                                             CartoType.Util.IntAttribute("fue",1),ref id,false);
```

But adding another with same code to another location is impossible. It is not drawing the second one. I have tried changing id but not worked.

Can I only add one map point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muzaffer, I'm sorry I didn't notice this question. As the CTO of CartoType I ought to have done. Yes, you can insert as many points as you like.

The problem you're having is caused by a conflict in object IDs. The first call sets the ID to one assigned by CartoType. If you leave that ID as it is, and use it in a new call, it will conflict with the ID of the object you just inserted.

The best way fix this problem is to change the ID to zero each time, just before you call InsertPointMapObject. Then CartoType will assign an ID and return it to you in 'ref id'.

If that doesn't work, please post a small repeatable example with all the code needed to reproduce the problem, and I'll look into it further.